# Sous-vide cooking for Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, cooking-bishul

[Sous-vide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-vide) is a method of cooking food slowly, at a precisely-controlled temperature. [This article](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/11/20/technology/personaltech/bringing-sous-vide-to-the-home-cook.html) in the *New York Times* reports that this method is becoming more and more accessible to and widespread among home cooks. As I understand it, a typical home setup could be:

- A large pot, full of water
- An electronically-controlled immersion heater, immersed in the water, with its thermostat set to maintain a particular water temperature
- Food, sealed in plastic bags or wrap, immersed in the water for a long time

As explained in the article, cook times could range from a short as an hour to as long as 72 hours, depending on the recipe.

Suppose one wants to use this method to have fresh-from-the-bath meat for *Shabbat*, setting everything up before *Shabbat*, and then removing and serving the meat on *Shabbat*.

**Are there any *Halachic* issues that either would prohibit this scheme altogether or that need to be taken into account in implementing it?**

I suspect that there could be issues related to:

- leaving food under the care of an adjustable device, that you might want to fiddle with, and
- causing the device to do more cooking as a result of removing the food from the water.

(Consult your own rabbi before implementing anything suggested here.)

Comment: How cooked is the food before Shabbat? (I don't know how long these things take. Are you talking like a 72 hour cook where it's almost done by candle lighting?)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I believe there are recipes with all different durations. Let's assume that recipe duration and timing are among the variables that are subject to alteration based on Halachic considerations.

Comment: +1 ...I was pretty sure that this was asked here before, but this was the only question that turned up in a MY search....

Comment: When I heard about this method of cooking, it sounded like the practice I've seen Sefardim do, of putting bags of rice and water in the Chamin (Cholent), and having it cook that way. -- see here for example: http://blog.thepeppermillinc.com/2014/05/our-culinary-travels-continuejewish.html

Comment: I'm confused. How is this different from cholent in a slow-cooker?

Comment: @Daniel, the main differences, to my mind, are that the device I described uses a thermostat and that it's immersed in water that the procedure I described includes interacting with on Shabbat.

Comment: @Daniel - it's trendier.

Comment: It would be funny if you could do this under Yad Soledet Bo.

Comment: @DoubleAA, if YS"B is, *lechumra*, 110 F, as [WP indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yad_soledet_bo) R'MF ruled, then it seems unlikely, but conceivable. According to [this chart](http://www.chefsteps.com/activities/sous-vide-time-and-temperature-guide), the recommended temperature for some kinds of fish is 104 F, though every other temperature listed is above 110 F.

Comment: Hatmono ought to be negotiable if you always put chicken stock cube in the water. I’m not a Posek. Ask yours. Yom Tov for sure it’s permitted.

Comment: See קובץ תורני אור השבת חוברת כ"ח עמ' י"ט for a Teshuva from Rav Asher Weiss discussing whether there is a Hatmanah issue.

Comment: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/895228/rabbi-jonathan-ziring/sous-vide-on-shabbat/

Comment: https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/6469/sous-vide-cookers-on-shabbos/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a shiur you can listen to [here](https://lcm.touro.edu/beis-medrash-ltalmud/torah/2016-2017/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/sous-vide-cooking-for-shabbos-and-through-shabbos.php) Rabbi Aryeh Lebowitz discussed some of the issues involved with sous vide which is begun before shabbos. They are:

- Shehiyah.
  Leaving foods on a heat source.
- Garuf Vikatum. Loosely, this refers to treating the heat source.
- Hatmana. Insulating the food.

All these points must be addressed as any one of these can make or break the allowance to leave the food on the heat source. 
See [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehiya) for more on the subject.

Whether or not sous vide is problematic concerning any one of these issues involved a machlokes achronim (for ashkenazim).

We would have to rely on two leniencies of the Chazon Ish and ignore the Mishna Berurah in order to alleviate the Shehiyah and Hatmana issues. We would also have to rely on Rav Aron Kotler's opinion about garuf vikatum when covering the controls and ignore Reb Moshe Feinstein's opinion that the actual heat source must be covered.

(He didn't focus on psak for a sfardi, but he did say that the mechaber would not allow shehiya in this case as it is not mitztamek v'ra lo. Cooking it longer does not make the food worse.)

Considering all this he said he did not want to give a hetter to do this for shabbos. Over the last year he spoke to Rabbis Schechter and Sacks but they have not given him a ruling.

(The shiur actually focused on a slightly different situation for which Rabbi Lebowitz was lenient, but all these points were addressed directly as far as shabbos is concerned).

Comment: What about Kederah Chayta? Even R Henkin should agree this is fine since you never cook on high heat with sous vide.

Comment: @IsaacMoses https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/common-questions-regarding-sous-vide-machines-involve-using-sous-vide-machine-shabbos-example-concern-hatmana-insulating-leaving-food-sous-vide-mach/

Comment: @DoubleAA do you have a link or reference to this R Henkin? Thank you

Comment: @shoel if you remind me in a week or two I'll hopefully have a chance to look more carefully, but iirc it's written in the annual shul ezras torah luach somewhere that he felt kedera chayta doesn't apply with our ovens since we can cook so fast

Comment: @Double I'm not sure what you are referring to, but sous vide is almost always above yad soledes bo as far as I know of.

Comment: I don't see why that would help @user

Comment: It's Teshuvot Ivra 15 @Shoel

Comment: @Double Rav Henkin was comparing American ovens to Russian ovens that literally took until the next day too cook. Sous Vide doesn't take that long. The novelty is that it could be left very long without necessarily being detrimental. But in reality most people agree there is an upper limit to how long to keep it cooking before it gets worse. It's not really that long https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/96116/how-long-is-too-long-for-sous-vide-steak. In truth I'm not so sure I agree that it's not mitztamek v'ra lo.

Comment: I admit to never having actually used a sous vide machine,but my impression was that the cuts of meat people use them on into shabbos are the tough ones like brisket with lots of connective tissue that really benefit from the long slow process and can't be cooked quicker as effectively, unlike steak in your link where sous vide is used for a different purpose of achieving a perfect medium/rare doneness

Answer (score 3):

[From the OK](https://www.ok.org/article/sous-vide/) regarding Hatmana:

> "There is a discussion amongst the Poskim about whether food wrapped
> in a plastic bag is included in the prohibition of Hatmana. Sous vide
> may not be included in the above prohibition for the following
> reasons:
>
> The food is not placed in a heated pot; the water and food are being
> cooked simultaneously. The bag is meant to protect the food from
> crumbling, but is not intended to insulate. The food is visible
> through the water and bag. There is no lid on the pot."

Answer (score 0):

From my research it would actually be a problem of *Hatmana*. The gemara talks about using *Chamei Teveria* to heat food/water on shabbos and says it is a problem. This is different than putting something in the cholent itself as there it is part of the cholent. Here the food is completely surrounded by the heating element which in this case is the water.

Comment: Where is that Gemara? Please [edit] in a more precise reference.

Comment: Perhaps a solution is to use broth instead of water, and then serve the broth too for lunch. Or just designate the water for tea or something.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for sharing your research here! Adding clear references and quotations would make this answer more valuable. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Also, I suggest that you [edit your profile](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name, unless 13452 is particularly meaningful to you. :)

Comment: @DoubleAA is there existing literature on food-as-*matmin*?

Comment: @IsaacMoses How could you ever put a kishka in the cholent? (I'm sure there is literature and there must be loopholes we can work with.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Alright, R' Chezzi Polk. :) (Given that this answer is correct that without employing such measures or loopholes, *hatmana* would present a problem, adding those sources and ideas for loopholes could really make this post a valuable contribution to the theoretical Halachic literature.)

Comment: See קובץ תורני אור השבת חוברת כ"ח עמ' י"ט for a Teshuva from Rav Asher Weiss discussing whether there is a Hatmanah issue.

Comment: https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/common-questions-regarding-sous-vide-machines-involve-using-sous-vide-machine-shabbos-example-concern-hatmana-insulating-leaving-food-sous-vide-mach/